# Are asynchronous virtual tables supported in SQLite for remote data sources?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am working with tabular data from an API, and I would like to interact with it through SQLite by creating a virtual table (SQLiteModule) that reads and writes to this remote data source. However, it seems that the virtual table mechanism in SQLite is entirely synchronous, which might not be ideal when working with data residing on a remote server.

I have not been able to find any asynchronous versions of the virtual table methods (e.g., BestIndex, Begin, Connect, Filter, Update), which leads me to believe that async virtual tables might not be supported.

Could someone please confirm whether my understanding is correct? If asynchronous virtual tables are indeed not supported, is it due to technical limitations, lack of development resources, or insufficient demand for such a feature? Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats correct - you can refer to https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw/issues/325

Currently there are no methods that are asyncio compatible.